# Menu link in a users perspective

Tags: navigation, user-expectation

This is probably a silly question but I'm going to design and develop a site for a bakery and me and my partner are having doubts about a link's text.

The page About Us, at first I thought of changing it's text to "the bakery" because it would be helpful for SEO but then I thought that maybe the user will be confused thinking it might be the page with the products.

Any thoughts about this? what's better?

Comment: "About The Bakery", though "About Us" will be clear to the user and unlikely to significantly impact SEO.

Comment: "About The Bakery" sounds good too, it keeps the idea and it's easier for the user to understand immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About, About US, even About the Bakery at least all contain the word about and as others have said it **is** what users expect to see. When doing a commercial website it is important to keep focused on standards otherwise you may as well throw up a picture of a Roll and see what happens.

Comment: came back to this and decided to go with the "About us" it's straight forward

Answer (score 0):

"About" or "About Us" seems to be standard for most websites. Some companies try to be creative and use other words as you have suggested. I don't see an issue with that. If you're using your SEO description, title, and keyword tags for each page then google will find them anyway. I think the navigation should be clear and concise. So keep the navigation simple and consistent throughout every page. Don't forget to think about your target audience. It will help you shape the way you present your content.

At the end of the day, the menu item name/title can be easily changed, so it shouldn't affect your design process too much.